# Why does RBAC have both roles and permissions?

Tags: design-patterns, permissions, roles, rbac

I most frequently see role-based access controls (RBAC) that require permissions to take an action. Subjects are assigned roles that grant them permissions.

I've recently come across an authorization library that does not have separate concepts for permissions and roles. Subjects are still granted roles, but authorization checks are done directly on the role and there is no concept of a permission. I worry that this design has shortcomings since I see it so much less often. What problems might arise due to roles and permissions being combined in this manner? What things are more difficult in this system?

Answer (score 2):

The RBAC standard [0] is defined over four levels. RBAC0 defines `users`, `roles`, `permissions` (which are `actions` to perform on `objects`), and their assignments. RBAC1 adds the definition role hierarchies, and RBAC2 adds constraints such as `separation of duty`. I don't thing RBAC3 is relevant here.
The point of authorisation models such as RBAC is to separate the policy from the code, so that changes to the policy can be made without modifying the code. This is especially important where system administrators don't have access to the code, or when they can't afford to re-deploy the system after each change to the access control policy.

The authorisation library you mention works differently, and I would argue that it does not actually implement the RBAC standard, at least from a pedantic point of view. By doing away with the permissions, the authorisation logic will be integrated into the code, looking for specific roles before granting (or refusing) access to some functionality. The advantage is that the administrator doesn't have to worry about permission assignments. The drawback however, is that any change to the roles required for a particular functionality will demand changes to the code itself, possibly in a lot of places. Missing some of them will lead to nasty bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, "Roles" are something an application admin will define based on business/user needs.  And "Permissions" are something that come predefined with the application. New "Permissions" are added to the system whenever there is a feature in the application that require access control, and this involves some development effort.  On the contrary, adding new roles is a matter of configuration and can be done from Application Interface (GUI or Command line tool)  Having "Roles" and assigning "permissions" to roles helps one to create multiple roles with varied degree of access.

In the system that you are have described, it seems creation of new "roles" will require change to application as each "role" seem to come with predefined permissions.

Based on what kind of flexibility you need, you may pick this new framework or not.  Sometimes, it is alright not to have user-definable roles if the application is catering to very specific needs.  Take example of [Tomcat Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) - which comes with few predefined roles - and that seems to be sufficient for most use cases.